# Maximum number of OS in a single hard disk

Tags: partitioning, operating-systems, multi-boot

I currently have a triple-boot setup in one dev machine (OSX/Win/Linux). I wonder how many more could I install.

I know Windows needs a primary partition, and Linux could be installed in an extended partition; what about OSX?

In theory, can you install 2 versions of Windows, 3 of OSX, and 1 Linux in a single hard disk?

Answer (score 2):

Depend of you OS and partition type,

if the OS can only boot from primary partition on a MBR partition table, the limit is 4,

if the OS can boot from a GUID partition table, as I know there is no limitation.

But i'm not sure at 100% of that (for the GUID Partition Table), I never tried.

Comment: ...And if the OS can boot from a logical MBR partition?

Comment: There is no limitations on logical partitions, the only limitation will be the total amount of partitions (primary + logical) that is 255.

Comment: How XP can live on a logical partition..http://www.sousuke.org/wiki/Installing_Windows_on_a_logical_partition

Comment: How to install and boot Windows on a Logical Parition...http://www.zyxware.com/articles/2008/07/20/how-to-install-and-boot-windows-on-a-logical-parition

Answer (score 2):

I've heard of someone having 40+ different operating systems on a single machine before. Certainly the standard Windows boot loader won't play nicely with multiple systems, but any modern open source boot loader would just fine.

I'd suspect you're limited to the number of partitions (and systems) you can fit on a disk.

Comment: I'm quite sure even `ntldr` can deal with many OSes just as fine as `grub` would.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that in theory, it depends on your boot-loader. For the sake of argument, let's say that your boot-loader is some sort of hypervisor. Then, the question is moot.

Comment: -1 Sarcasm not needed.